# Sequelize: How to query a parent column by the sum of an associated table's column

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Please I need help.

I have 2 tables `Articles` and `Ratings`. I associated Articles and Ratings so articles can have many ratings.
Ratings have a column `rating` which is an integer.
Now I want to query the database with sequelize to return the top 5 highest rated articles from the database.
So basically the query should be able to add all the `rating` columns of all Ratings for all the articles, then return the top 5 articles with the highest rating.
How do I go about this please?

Answer (score 0):

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');    
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

     Article.findAll({
                    include: [{
                        model: Rating
                    }],
                    where : {
                        id : {
                            [Op.in] : [connection.literal(`select ArticleID from Rating  WHERE rating =(SELECT MAX(rating) FROM Rating) LIMIT 5'`)]
                        }
                    }
                })
                .then(result => {
                    res.json(result);
                }).catch(error=>{
                    res.json(error);
                });
```

I hope this will work ! If not play around this code you'll get your answer ! :-).

And do let me know if it worked !